# Which scripture is the source of the chant 'Asatoma Sadgamaya Thamaso Maa Jyothir Gamaya...?'

Tags: mantras, identification-request

From [this](http://www.saidarshan.org/baba/docs/slveda.html) link, I found the following verse. Which Hindu scripture is the source of this verse?

> Asatoma Sadgamaya
>
> Thamaso Maa Jyothir Gamaya
>
> Mrithyor Maa Amrutham Gamaya
>
> Aum Shanti Shanti Shantihi
>
> **Meaning**: Lead me from the unreal to the real. Lead me from darkness to light. Lead me from death to immortality. May there be peace everywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here](http://hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/hinduism/upanishads/brihad.asp#adh1) is the Source of this Verse from Brihad-Aranyaka Upanishad

> असतो मा सदगमय ॥ तमसो मा ज्योतिर्गमय ॥ मृत्योर्मामृतम् गमय ॥

**Meaning:**

> 'Lead me from the unreal to the real! Lead me from darkness to light! Lead me from death to immortality!'

*Now when he says,' Lead me from the unreal to the real,' the unreal is verily death, the real immortality. He therefore says, 'Lead me from death to immortality, make me immortal.'
When he says,'Lead me from darkness to light,' darkness is verily death, light immortality. He therefore says, 'Lead me from death to immortality, make me immortal.'
When he says,'Lead me from death to immortality,' there is nothing there, as it were, hidden (obscure, requiring explanation).*